# Quantum Invariants of 3-Manifolds and TQFT

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, low-dimensional-topology

If I understand the theory of quantum invariants of 3-manifolds correctly (possibly I don't), different presentations of 3-manifolds produce different TQFTs but the same quantum invariants (Reshetikhin-Turaev invariants for example).  These invariants are said to be analogous to observables in quantum field theory.  Do the TQFTs have a physical analogy?

---

EDIT:
While trying to be more specific in my example below (per a commenters request), I realized I was thinking about TQFTs incorrectly and that my original question didn't make much sense.  However, a new question fell out when I tried to clarify below.

Here is my attempt to be more specific via an example and my new question:  Take for example [this video at 1:00:50](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RcIvzLvvFI&list=PL0a6GqRfGOz1q5f5ogPGpUNA-wNerDElp&index=12).  The speaker gives a presentation in terms of generators of a 3-dimensional TQFT for $\mathbb{R}P^3$ using Heedgaard decomposition as a tool.  He then calculates the value produced by the field theory on the generators in his presentation of $\mathbb{R}P^3$.  There are other Heedgard decompositions and presentations of $\mathbb{R}P^3$ which will give a different value when you apply the field theory to the generators.  However, the Reshetikhin-Turaev invariant should be the same for all presentations of $\mathbb{R}P^3$.  I read somewhere (can't remember exactly where) that the Reshetikhin-Turaev invariant corresponds to an observable in Physics. Does the value of the field theory prior to calculatng the RT invariant have a physical interpretation?

Comment: I don’t understand the question. Can you ask something more specific?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan My question didn't make sense.  Attempting to be more specific made me realize that.  However, a similar question fell out during the process.